# How can I de-share third level .name domain which would allow me to register the second level domain?

Tags: name, domains

Sometime ago I registered a third level `.name` domain of the type **john.doe.name**. I just realised that I could have registered the entire second level domain **doe.name**, which would grant me control of the third level one anyway.

Since I already registered the third level, **doe.name** is now "shared". I have 2 questions:

1. How do I check if I am the only one using the shared second level domain? (normal whois lookup doesn't give any result)
2. Can I "de-share" the domain and buy the entire second level domain?

Comment: .name domains have special rules for third level registrations. Please keep this in mind before answering. You can actually directly register a third level domain on .name

Comment: When .NAME started it was only for domains like firstname.lastname.name you could NOT register just lastname.name. This has changed over the years.

Answer (score 2):

See [this post on how to convert a 3rd level .name domain to a 2nd level .name domain](http://blog.ebrahim.org/2004/09/29/howto-converting-a-3rd-level-name-domain-to-a-2nd-level-name-domain/). Summarizing the steps:

1. Confirm that you are the only one using the second level domain.
2. Issue deletion of third level registrations
3. On the sixth day after issuing the delete commands, register the second level domain name

Be sure to refer to the original post on caveats related to the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

Most common second-level names under .name *cannot be registered at all*. They are reserved by the registry.

If you [run a whois search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/24455/17007) on such a name, you'll get the following result (e.g. this query for `bianchi.name`):

> Not available for second level registration.
>   Third level registrations may be available on this shared name.

A name that is *not* reserved will return:

> No match for domain "IURHGBREIU.NAME".

If your surname is common in almost any human language, it is probably already reserved and you would not have been able to register it anyway.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I am afraid this doesn't answer neither questions though. Since I already registered the third level, of course the second level will be reserved (i.e. at least by me!). My question is whether I can check if there is any other person using the second level. The second question is: in case I am the only one using the second level, is there a way I can acquire control of the entire second level?

Comment: If you successfully registered a third level name, then the second level was already reserved. You won't get it unreserved by cancelling your registration.

Answer (score 0):

Third level domains and domain hacks are usually not in a free market with clearly stated rules on a national level.

Unless we're talking about governatively sanctioned ones like `example.co.uk` or `example.co.za`, ok.

But I've got the impression we're not.

Who did you bought this from? A big name domain dealer? Then he was probably reselling from some privates.

Do a [whois](http://www.geektools.com/whois.php) on your second level domain name, <surname>.com there you should find the name of the private individuals that owns it. Then you'll have to contact them, and ask'em for their price.

Possibly on www.<surname>.com you'll also find contact information.

Also, you should already have a contract standing, for the third level you're operating, **with this very same guys**. check the papers/pdfs that the registrar handed you. There might be more informations about them on those.

I'd usually expect this kind of price to be **HUGE**, but it hardly hurts to ask.

Comment: Hi ZJR. Thanks for you post. I don't think you understood the question. '.name' is an actual domain type; I didn't use it as an example.  Buying the xyz.name is very cheap. On the other hand, it looks like you think I have 'john.geocities.com' and I want to buy 'geocities.com'. Its not like that. '.name' domain work differently.